DOT 3, DOT 4 brake fluid. Can you mix them?
Only for topping off, in a vehicle that takes dot 3, but only dot 4 is readily available.
Can they be mixed?

This question is similar to: Can I put DOT 4 brake fluid into DOT 3 brake?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, they can be mixed, but once mixed you have to consider it to be DOT3 after that. Don't try to "split the difference" or average what you think you have. Just consider it DOT3 from that point forward.
Your better bet would be to purge all of the DOT3 and replace completely with DOT4 if you want to have the DOT4 advantages. To do this would just be to bleed the brakes completely.
